# corrupted Arch Linux OS after accessing partition from Windows 7(dual boot)

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have(had) Arch Linux as my primary OS on my laptop and then I installed Windows 7 to dual boot.

All setup went very well and was working.

After a day or two, I had installed ext2fsd to mount & access ext4 partition.

After mounting it, I think my win-7 was virus infected (one which creates folder without any name[using hidden chars] and moves all content into that and hides that folder and creates visible shortcut to that), and it did the same thing to my ext4 partition and since then it took me on a spin, I am fixing ever since and I am never able to recover from that.

I have manually copied all content from hidden folder to root of drive and stuff.

I think I have corrupt my OS and I am at the point where I might have to format but i want to recover and learn

error message that GRUB is displaying:

```
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin.init does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own.

sh: can’t access tty; job control turned off

[rootfs /]#
```

can someone help me with this, so that I won't have to format the damn OS

I don't want all this hours I spent to fix this go for nothing

If partition is corrupted, can I chroot from bootable media and fix it with `pacman -Syu`

PS: I think i have deleted file in ext4 partition with UIID as name

Comment: You cant install Windows after linux as it overwrites the bootsector.  I am sure this is fixable, but I would let someone more familiar with the process explain.  I can break linux real good-like, fixing it isnt my strength.

Comment: Dual boot is working fine, Grub is loading ok and i can even boot into Windows as well, just that when i try to boot into Arch Linux from grub, it fails with /sbin.init does not exist message

Comment: Also, i can view and explore linux partition from windows with ext explorer...everything is there

Comment: This is to be expected. Windows overwrote the boot sector so Linux can't boot.

Comment: the order of installation was Windows(7) first, then installed Linux(Arch) , was happy with setup since everything was working fine( both Win7 and Arch), used this setup for more than month, one day needed to use windows, used ext2fsd and boom everything went south, don't think this is "boot sector overwritten" issue, but i can give that a shot

Comment: chroot gave me some insights and was able to solve it by re-creating bin, sbin , lib and lib64 soflinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, windows has corrupted the soft links in root directory

Broken links were

- bin -> was **`usr\bin`** instead of **`usr/bin`**
- sbin -> was **`usr\bin`** instead of **`usr/bin`**
- lib -> was **`usr\lib`** instead of **`usr/lib`**  `&
- lib64 -> was **`usr\lib`** instead of **`usr/lib`**

> fixing this links have solved my problem and I am posting this answer from my beloved arch linux distro